# User settings and access control in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, access-control, settings

I have a webapp build with rails. Nothing complicated so far. Now I would like to restrict some areas for the user. I would like to implement two roles, `User` and `Admin`. Clearly the admin can do much more, like use DELETE in some of the controller methods. But there is even more. The user should be able to set some settings. For example he can set his profile to private, so only his friends can see his content. I am not sure how to build all of this with rails.

I did some research and found those two:
https://github.com/elabs/pundit
https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings

Maybe a combination of those two would get me to the way I want the app to be?

Answer (score 0):

If the app is going to be used used by real users i would go for the devise gem(https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) It allows user to create accounts, retrieve lost passwords etc. By default it allows users to edit their "profile"(rather their personal data), it should be easy to add a checkbox to toggle public/private profiles.

In conjunction with cancancan(https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) you can assign roles to users, without having two different classes(Users and Admins for example).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will take a look at it. Now to add an attribute for (private/public) should be no problem, but let's try to think big. The user should set some more settings like "Enable Notifications", "Privacy Settings", "Generel", etc. Should I add for every single user setting just an attribute in the User model?